# How to pass a string to test.cgi on a web-server?

Tags: c

Situation : `test.cgi?a=b` is read by a web browser.

Mission : Instructing it to print `?a=b` or perhaps anything that it can grab.

Current output :

```
(null)
test
```

Desired output :

```
?a=b
test
```

test.c

```
include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

fputs("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", stdout);
printf("%s<br>", argv[1]);
fputs("test", stdout);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    fputs("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", stdout);
    printf("%s<br>", getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
    fputs("test", stdout);

    return 0;
}
```